# How to efficiently find 0/1 loss for a linear classification model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

Machine Learning newbie here. I am trying to calculate the 0/1 loss of my linear model after training the weights on my training data. I have seen a lot of answers that use for loops here. Is there a way to vectorize it? My attempts were the following:

```
prob = np.dot(X_train,w)>=0

pred = [int(i) for i in prob]

error = np.sum(pred)/X_train.shape[0]
```

where w are the trained weights and X_train is shaped as number of samples x number of features

Comment: please spend some time to learn how to format your code (it's really easy); it's only fair, since you ask for our time here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But this should help:

```
prob = np.dot(X_train,w)>=0  

pred = [int(i) for i in prob]  
z0= [1 if y_val[i,0]!=pred[i] else 0 for i in range(len(pred)) ]
error = sum(z0)/len(z0)
```